# Beginner C#: using object o, RoutedEventArgs sender

Tags: c#, silverlight, timer

Basically I want my application to run a timer, I found the following code to use:

```
public void StartTimer(object o, RoutedEventArgs sender)
{
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer myDispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    myDispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100); // 100 Milliseconds 
    myDispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Each_Tick);
    myDispatcherTimer.Start();
}

// A variable to count with.
int i = 0;

// Raised every 100 miliseconds while the DispatcherTimer is active.
public void Each_Tick(object o, EventArgs sender)
{
    myTextBlock.Text = "Count up: " + i++.ToString();
}
```

But I don't understand how to call StartTimer,

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StartTimer();
}
```

Doesn't work because it says no overload takes zero arguments, but I don't know what arguments to use for object sender and RoutedEventsArgs e such that it works.

I know this is a beginner question but I have been doing a lot of searching to no avail, would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Use the same ones that were given to the Click method.. `StartTimer(sender, e);`..

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you should just remove the parameters from `StartTimer` -- they're not used, and aren't necessary:

```
public void StartTimer()
```

Note that for the two event handlers "Button_Click_1" and "Each_Tick", the method parameters are needed.  To subscribe to an event, the handler's arguments have to match the signature of the event.  But "StartTimer" is just a normal method, so it can have whatever arguments.